# AngularJS UI Bootstrap Tab Sample

Tags: tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying out a sample to create tabs with [ui bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap). The sample works on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r7G6jIb2Wf34qZ5wHDsb?p=preview) but doesn't work when I try the same code locally.

I have the right references to the javascript file (script.js) from the index.html.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was because plunker used a [network-path reference](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). When viewing the same file locally it translates to a file:// protocol. Replacing it with https worked!